# Asset pipeline for jquery plugins with stylesheets and images linked

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

Got a trouble when including some external javascript code (example can be jquery.treeview plugin with css and images included) - in vendor/assets (where this should go) it seems it doesnt work with images. Any experience or example of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's because you need to correct `/images/foo.jpg` to the new scheme of `/assets/foo.jpg`

If not, please include logs and examples.

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of what Zach said, the solution I've used is to modify the js/css files to be erb templates, and used asset_path('treeview/foo.jpg') to replace '/treeview/foo.jpg', and move all plugin images to the app/assets/images/treeview folder.

This will make everything work swimmingly, but it is less than ideal in requiring hacking up plugins before they work with the new system.

Of course, you can also keep your CSS and JS files in /public/javascripts and just javascript_include_tag them as usual, but you'll lose the precompile/bundle/compress functionality the asset pipeline provides.

Comment: Well, what I would really like, is not to modify js/css files at all. This way would be updates of this external stuff not that painful...

Comment: Like I said, if you want to just use straight-up plugins, use the old, non-asset-pipeline solutions.  Put the .js file in /public/javascripts and use javascript_include_tag('jquery.treeview') in your <head>, then move the images associated with the plugin into /public/treeview.  Files in /public are publicly routable with no asset pipeline involvement.